# What's an open source software with ideally no more than 100 functions or objects and has lots of documentation?

Tags: open-source, software-testing

I have a group project starting this week and the assignment is to take an open source software and write a test plan, create a graph based coverage diagram, use it to construct test cases, run those tests, and report the results. The teacher said ideally the open source software should be no more than 100 functions or objects and have lots of documentation so that we can experiment with black box testing. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.